# What's the best way to initialize an MVC Controller with multiple parameters of the same type using Castle Windsor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

In my MVC application, I'm registering all of my controllers using reflection in the Application_Start handler. This basically creates all types that are used on any controller parameter and adds it to the container.

I now have a situation where I have multiple parameters on my controller that are of the *same* type. Here is a simple example of my problem:

```
public class ClassA : ICustomType
{ ... }

public class ClassB : ICustomType
{ ... }

public class CustomController : Controller
{
   public CustomController(ICustomType a, ICustomType b)
   { ... }
}
```

I know that I can define CustomController in my web.config file using the `<components>` group. However, I'm curious to know if there is a way that I could specify 'ClassA' as my first parameter and 'ClassB' as my second parameter outside of my web.config file??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
container.Register(
   Component.For<ICustomType>().Named("a").ImplementedBy<ClassA>(),
   Component.For<ICustomType>().Named("b").ImplementedBy<Classb>()
);
```